# Cross-domain iframe communication without HTML 5

Tags: gwt, iframe, cross-domain

I want to know about some method like `window.postMessage()` for cross-domain IFrame communication in GWT without the use of HTML 5 since it is not supported by older browsers.

Comment: And _older browsers_ here mean IE6 and IE7. `postMessage` is in IE8 and every other browser out there for *years*! Win XP reaching its EOL in less than 2 years will put IE8 to death, so there really is no reason to support IE6/7. http://caniuse.com/x-doc-messaging

Comment: I need some method to work in IE7 too..

Comment: I feel sorry for you (sincerely). Go search the archives of ajaxian.com, I'm sure you'll find something (communicate through the `window.name` for instance, from memory)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://mattsnider.com/hash-hack-for-cross-domain-iframe-communication/.
It is really good.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.